# LINQtoSQL search mechanism

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, search, linq-to-sql

```
SessionIDs ids = (SessionIDs)Session["IDs"];
BSDataContext ct = new BSDataContext();

var customers = from cust in ct.tblCustomers
                where cust.AccountID == ids.accountID && drpFilter.SelectedValue.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text.ToString())
                join mem in ct.tblCustomerMemberships on cust.CustomerID equals mem.CustomerID
                select new { cust.CustomerID, cust.Mobile, cust.BusinessPhone, cust.Code, cust.Email, cust.HomePhone, mem.Membership, Name = cust.FirstName + cust.LastName };
grdCustomer.DataSource = customers;
grdCustomer.DataBind();
```

I have a record that starts with `Waqar`, but it is not showing.

```
drpFilter.SelectedValue = cust.Name and txtSearch.Text = Waqar
```

Kindly help me

Comment: Take the SQL that LINQ generates and try it out. If that is the same result, it is not a LINQ issue but you formlating the wrong query. You join - maybe that has no membership? We cna not do your debugging for you at this level. Not our job and we do not see your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see one problem with this:

```
 SessionIDs ids = (SessionIDs)Session["IDs"];
            BSDataContext ct = new BSDataContext();
            var customers = from cust in ct.tblCustomers
                            where cust.AccountID == ids.accountID &&
  drpFilter.SelectedValue.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text.ToString()) //<-- HERE
                                join mem in ct.tblCustomerMemberships
                                on cust.CustomerID equals mem.CustomerID
                                select new { ... };
```

If you execute this: `drpFilter.SelectedValue.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text.ToString())` it just gives you a boolean.
Therefor the SQL generated looks somethng like this:

```
WHERE AccountID = @p1 AND TRUE
```